# JQuery not working;simple alert("hello");

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, node.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

I wrote an inline function that for some reason when I ran onclick says it doesn't exists so I tried to simplify it completely till it works but I found out even this code doesn't work. It does work on a empty page though!It is located under all my other code in said page; no body tags only DIVs - right after the last  div .Maybe it is because of the frameworks I'm using? I have firebase/angularjs/nodejs. I also tried to do document ready calls and console.log(); getting no errors but also nothing popping up either.
EDIT: it is literally not a duplicate because I tried all other solutions. Here is more code: I tried to put it into the last div and outside of it.

```
<!-- <a class="btn-for-pw" ng-href="">Forgot Password?</a> -->

              </form><!-- end of #signupForm -->

          </div>

          <!--Footer-->
          <div class="modal-footer text-center">
              <a ng-href="#/register">Create an Account</a>
          </div>

      </div>
      <!--/Form with header-->

  </div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"/>
<script>
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

Comment: It doesnt work when I do <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> and <script> alert("hello"); </script> either.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script><script>alert('hello');</script>`

Comment: tried again to make sure, still no.

Comment: where is the `</script>` of your jquery?

Comment: I tried what the answer bellow said. I had it seperate before too, which was just instead of bellow answer , your answer.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that.. But try to look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctsvre1y/2/) vs this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctsvre1y/) that is similar to your code. Try to run those.

Comment: What I was trying to say was I tried both of these at the location in the code provided(the first fiddle being what is in my current code) and nether did anything.

Comment: have you notice that you don't have `</script>` in your jquery code? Try to look at the path also if its correct..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting another script tag after you include your jQuery source. as the script inside will be disregarded.

Here is a j[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thedos/5cdmh9cr/2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"/>
<script>
    alert("hello");
</script>
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: same thing nothing pops up. I will restart my chrome just to make sure again.

Comment: I included a jsfiddle that you can have a look at.

Comment: Make sure you have this code in a .html file

Comment: I included more code. It is an html file.

Comment: Idk if it helps though because it is just the end of the form for signing in.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"/>`  line all together? Also does your console output any error?

Comment: I been stuck on this for a while hence like I tried all the stack overflow stuff. And I think so because there is a javascript folder with a jQuery.3.11.min file thing, but simple inline code doesnt work for some reason. My problem is also I don't see how anything is connected because no includes of any kind - ( this is for an actual site that I barley got on board with)

Comment: And yeah nothing thrown at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just don't want to ask for help from work because trying to impress :P

Comment: Its a bit hard to figure out what is going wrong from here. All I can think of is that you are running the wrong file all together for example you may have made a copy of the file and are trying to run the old version (This may seem silly but it catches people out more often than not).

Comment: I actually have a counter to that: when I had my inline function it was def throwing me errors that the function didnt exist and stopped when I deleted it from said file.

Comment: whatever im just gonna select this answer and talk to work .D:< Thanks anyway guyssssssssssss.

Comment: Please let me know how you go and I can edit my answer to fit